# Is it safe to use the session id as a filename in PHP?

Tags: php, security, session

In an PHP web application, I am using the session id as a filename. At a certain point, these files are deleted, with code like

```
unlink('tmp/'.session_id());
```

I am aware of the fact that a user could change his/her session id. Hence I wonder if the session id could be changed to something like "/../../etc/passwd".

My question is now, if that kind of "hacking" is possible, and how I could protect my code best.

Thank you in advance, for your answers!

Comment: I know about the dangers and prevention methods regarding users hijacking other users' sessions, this is not an issue in my case at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a **very** screwed up set-up, an user will never be able to directly change his session ID as this should never be a direct parameter - it should be used to verify if it exists, but never to create an arbitrary session based on that name.

If it is not the case in your system, however, the recommendation is to sanitize: `preg_replace("#([^0-9a-f]+)#i","",session_id());`

Comment: Okay, thanks - if it saves very screwed up set-ups, it's better to use it. Other people might use that software on their servers...

Comment: @user2349661: if they might use it on their servers, you might want to check that the `tmp` folder exists and is writable across all platforms before implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to replace all bad chars:

```
$sess = session_id();
$clean_sess = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/Uis", "", $sess);
unlink('tmp/'.$clean_sess);
```